# Can't update Quantity in Decimal Points in DarrylDeCode Cart Package

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

I have developed an E-commerce website using Laravel and now I am trying to update the cart with the Decimal Quantity but it automatically round it off to nearest number when update function is called.

The products quantity can be in **"KG"** and can be **1.0, 1.25, 1.50** and so on.

**P.S: I am using Laravel DarrylDecode Cart Service Provider**

Here is the code of the Cart Update Function that I wrote and working fine for non decimal quantity numbers:

```
public function update(Request $request)
{
    $row = count($request->id);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $row; $i++) {
        Cart::update($request->id[$i], [
            'quantity' => array(
                'relative' => false,
                'value' => $request->quantity[$i],
            ),
        ]);
    }
}
```

Here is the code of the update function provided by Darryldecode I found it on following path : Vendor/darryldecode/Cart/Cart.php

```
public function update($id, $data)
{
    if ($this->fireEvent('updating', $data) === false) {
        return false;
    }

    $cart = $this->getContent();
    $item = $cart->pull($id);

    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        // if the key is currently "quantity" we will need to check if an arithmetic
        // symbol is present so we can decide if the update of quantity is being added
        // or being reduced.
        if ($key == 'quantity') {
            // we will check if quantity value provided is array,
            // if it is, we will need to check if a key "relative" is set
            // and we will evaluate its value if true or false,
            // this tells us how to treat the quantity value if it should be updated
            // relatively to its current quantity value or just totally replace the value
            if (is_array($value)) {
                if (isset($value['relative'])) {
                    if ((bool)$value['relative']) {
                        $item = $this->updateQuantityRelative($item, $key, $value['value']);
                    } else {
                        $item = $this->updateQuantityNotRelative($item, $key, $value['value']);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                $item = $this->updateQuantityRelative($item, $key, $value);
            }
        } elseif ($key == 'attributes') {
            $item[$key] = new ItemAttributeCollection($value);
        } else {
            $item[$key] = $value;
        }
    }

    $cart->put($id, $item);
    $this->save($cart);
    $this->fireEvent('updated', $item);
    
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the source code of this package (https://github.com/darryldecode/laravelshoppingcart/blob/23fa7ef44f404d97131d73701a5dc6c37361d335/src/Darryldecode/Cart/Cart.php#L815):

```
protected function updateQuantityNotRelative($item, $key, $value)
{
    $item[$key] = (int)$value;

    return $item;
}
```

This is the function you use when set `'relative' => false,`. It always set the value to `int`.

With `relative => true` it uses the same approach with (int) type hint:

```
protected function updateQuantityRelative($item, $key, $value)
{
    if (preg_match('/\-/', $value) == 1) {
        $value = (int)str_replace('-', '', $value);

        // we will not allowed to reduced quantity to 0, so if the given value
        // would result to item quantity of 0, we will not do it.
        if (($item[$key] - $value) > 0) {
            $item[$key] -= $value;
        }
    } elseif (preg_match('/\+/', $value) == 1) {
        $item[$key] += (int)str_replace('+', '', $value);
    } else {
        $item[$key] += (int)$value;
    }

    return $item;
}
```

I guess this package, by design, doesn't allow non integer quantities. As an alternative, you can design your application to use `grams (g)` instead of `kilograms (kg)`, and them use integer, like 1.5kg = 1500g , or use a different package.

Comment: Which package to use because the requirement of the client is KG

Comment: Nevermind I have done it just removed the **(int)** from **updateQuantityNotRelative** function and its now working as per requirement.

Comment: It's always risky to do that. I suggest you to create a new class that `extends Cart`, then you can overwrite this method and use your own class. If you need to install this package again in a different local you will keep your change.

Answer (score 0):

1- in `darryldecode/laravelshoppingcart` config file you need to change the value of `SHOPPING_FORMAT_VALUES` to `true` to enables `format_numbers`

2- change `SHOPPING_DECIMALS` to the number of decimals you want.

by default `SHOPPING_DECIMALS` is set to `0`.

but for the best practice you should use the smallest unit as default for amount feilds (money, quantity, salary).

in your code you should use `1000` insted of `1` for `KG`
and calculate it in your code to display and store it the way you like.

Comment: I have changed it to following:

`'format_numbers' => env('SHOPPING_FORMAT_VALUES', true),

    'decimals' => env('SHOPPING_DECIMALS', 1000),`

But cart page is now giving error
**A non well formed numeric value encountered**

Comment: you may run `php artisan config:clear` to get the changes

Comment: and `'decimals' => env('SHOPPING_DECIMALS', 3)` for 3 decimal points number is good